# SQLAlchemy core - get a list of bindparams in a query, or check if one exists by name?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

With sqlalchemy core you can bind a parameter and then fill it in at execution time, e.g.

```py
query = select([my_table]).limit(bindparam('lim'))

session.execute(query, lim=10)
```

I have it so that the queries received may or may not be using certain parameters. So I'd like a way to be able to verify if a parameter exists or even to get a list of the parameters that have to be substituted at execution time. E.g. this might be done to allow limits in the query like above.

The values which may need to be substituted will be known, so it's just a case of checking if they're actually there. At the moment as a small temporary workaround I have found I can set the names to complex things like random strings of digits, and then just check if those exist in the query's string form. Of course other solutions exists like storing/passing which ones have/haven't been used, but I'm looking to see if there's a way just to check which ones exist. and are being expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the parameters from the compiled query, like this:

```py
>>> q = select([test1]).limit(bindparam('lim')) 
>>> c = q.compile()
>>> c.params
{'lim': None}
```